# R2WinBUGS - Problems

Tags: r

I am trying to adjust na hierarchical bayesian model. The initial code was in bugs but I would like to run it in R.
Unfortenatly I have received this error message. Could anyone help me? Thanks

```
model is syntactically correct
data loaded
model compiled
initial values generated, model initialized
Sampling has been started ...
Error in handleRes(res) : NA
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/Ivone Figueiredo/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/BRugs/exec/BugsHelper.exe" "C:/Users/IVONEF~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8anrb5" "C:/Users/IVONEF~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8anrb5/trash" "file135839412c64.bug" "C:/Users/IVONEF~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8anrb5/cmds.txt" "1"' had status 144
```

Comment: This is not answerable without showing us the code you used to run the model.